# MVC Azure AD Authorization Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, authorization, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have issues using the `[Authorize]` attribute in MVC.

Here are the steps taken:

1. Create Azure Active Directory called `TestAD1`
2. Insert serveral users in the AD
3. Create a Group called `TestGroup1`
4. Using visual studio 2013 create a MVC project with `Windows Authentication` as authentication method
5. Insert `[Authorize]` above a controler method
6. Publish the site
7. In the azure portal configure the website to use azure active directory as authentication

These steps work fine, everything acts like expected the problem is when i change the authorize attribute to:

`[Authorize(Roles=@"TestAD1\TestGroup1")]`

I always get "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I am aware of the following solutions but it doesn't fit my project needs:
 * Write my own `RoleProvider`
 * Use web.config to manage permissions

Comment: I don't believe the security groups, translated in Roles come with AD tenant name as in normal Windows Authentication. Change your attribute to `[Authorize(Roles="TestGroup1")]` and try again. Also, do **not** set `Windows Authentication` if you are deploying to Cloud.

Comment: Hi astaykov, thank you for your response, i have tried different combinations of Roles="***" and none of them work, which authentication should i use in the cloud ?

Answer (score 4):

Luka, we've recently enabled roles claim for Azure AD integrated applications. Here's an ASP.NET web application that uses Azure AD App Roles to perform authorization using the [Authorize] attribute: https://github.com/dushyantgill/VipSwapper/tree/master/TrainingPoint

Regd your current setup, security group names in Azure AD are not transmitted as roles claim. Neither does Windows Authentication work to hook up auth for your cloud service with Azure AD.

Hope this helps.

Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Why does the app use a custom authorize attribute? Why can't you just use the baked-in `[Authorize(Roles = "")]` one?